# Java String Array

Tags: java, android, sorting

i have two array

```
String a[]={"11","02","43","24","05","86","37","28","29","10"};
String b[]={"a","c","f","q","w","x","z","x","s","r"};
```

i want to sort array a[] in ascending order

and the result may like

```
String a[]={"02","05","10","11","24","28","29","37","43","86"};
String b[]={"c","w","r","a","q","x","s","z","f","x"};
```

how can i get result like above using **java**?
any sorting method available in java?

Comment: What have you tried? And you should use some other data structure. You cannot arrange element of 2nd array according to the sorted 1st array. May be a `Map` you need.

Comment: @Rohit: Sure you can, you just wouldn't want to.  Also your idea of a `Map` is that much better when you consider there's a map that keeps its keys sorted: `TreeMap`.

Comment: @MarkPeters.. Well, actually by `cannot` I meant it wouldn't be `feasible` solution enough. It's like living an `Ancient life` in the `modern world`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way would be to link the 2 pieces of data together in some way instead of having them in separate arrays. Many people have suggested a Map which would work great. Depending on exactly what you are trying to do, I would also consider a new class with 2 variables that implement Comparable. Comparable defines the natural ordering of a class when it is in a Collection (in this instance an array) if Collections.sort is not given a different Comparator to use. It would look something like this:

```
    public class Data implements Comparable{ 
    private String stringOne;
    private String stringTwo;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object obj) {
        stringOne.compareTo((String)obj);
    }
```

Somewhere else call:

```
    Collections.sort(locationOfDataCollection);
```

You could then create one Collection of Data and access the other String with a getter method. This implementation also would make it simple in future (see Strategy Design) if in some instances the natural order needed to be overridden with a new Comparator (e.g. sort by stringTwo).

Answer (score 4):

Since you have 2 *related* sets of data, I would either link these via a `Pair<String,String>` type object and then into a `List<Pair>`, or put them into a `Map<String,String>`.

Perhaps the first solution is more intuitive e.g.

```
public class Pair implements Comparable<Pair> {
   public String first;
   public String second;

   // equals/hashcode etc.
}
```

Once they're in a standard Java collection, numerous solutions exist for sorting these. e.g. in the above `Pair` I've implemented the [`Comparable<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface which the [Collections sorting mechanisms](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) will make use of.

Comment: +1, I've found Pair to be an immensely useful abstraction.  It'd also be worth it to implement a "zip" utility method to combine two collections into a collection of Pairs (and the inverse, "unzip").

Answer (score 0):

There is no methods for directly doing this in Java. You have two options.

1) Define a `Map<String, String>`, put all the pairs in it (like ("11", "a")). Sort first array (or the keys of the map) and retrieve the elements of the map in that order.

2) Create an object that holds each par, create a `List` with it, and sort comparing only by the number (implement `Comparable` or create a `Comparator`).

Answer (score 0):

One issue you'll need to be aware of is that Strings don't sort according to the same rules as integers.  You are likely to be surprised by what you get if you leave the array by which you sort as String.